# Accessing the bits of the binary equivalent of a number

Tags: arrays, binary, numbers

I've tried applying this logic by creating an array and storing the binary equivalent into the array element and then accessing them using their index position, but it takes a lot of time. Is their any better algorithm for accomplishing this task?

Comment: The numbers in a computer are already stored in binary!

Comment: Step 1: Write down precisely what your task is. That's an essential ability for any software developer, writing down exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

I'm trying to code the solution of the above problem. I need to find all possible subsets of a given integer array. Sum up the elements of the individual subsets and accumulate the the fibonacci(sum of elements of a present subset), where fibonacci(n) means, nth fibonacci. And finally return the accumulated sum modulo e9+7.